# Surface book keyboard won't work in scientific Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, redhat, surface

I installed scientific linux 7.4(based on redhat 7.4) in my surface book. My touch pad is working correctly but the problem is the keyboard won't work in this OS. I also found that an external usb keyboard works correctly with it. I have Ubuntu and Windows beside this OS, but I don't have any problem with them. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I should mention that scientific linux is base on redhat with extra features

Comment: Send a bugreport: https://www.scientificlinux.org/community/get-involved/

Comment: there is not any where for bug report in this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/6ca920/ms_surface_keyboard_does_it_play_nice_with_linux/ 
you would need at least 4.10 kernel for the surface to work properly.

The kernel version in your system can be obtained by `uname -rv` in the terminal.

The easiest solution is to update the kernel / linux-firmware package from your distro package manager.

If this does not work, probably you would need to reconfigure or update and reconfigure the kernel (e.g. to the latest stable mainline from https://www.kernel.org/)

A nice guide for configuration  can be found here https://www.dotslashlinux.com/2017/09/11/the-linux-kernel-configuration-guide-part-11/

Comment: Tank you for your answer @gart1 . My kernel is 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 .  How can I update my kernel to 4.10 ?

Comment: I'm not aware of the SL distribution, but I managed to dig out that there is unofficial support for newer kernels. I think following http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php would work for you.

Comment: Here are some detailed instructions:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-upgrade-kernel-version-in-centos-7/

Comment: GREAT. Tank you sooooo much @gat1 . I am so HAPPY . I tried to fix it for several weeks but I can't find any solution . I use the last link structure you sent and it work. now i use my keyboard for typing.

Comment: Is there a way for upgrading my kernel without needing to network ? Because I installed SL6.9 and it doe'snt connect to network so I could'nt upgrade my kernel.